# On Windows 11 Pro is it safe to use my computer while chkdsk /f /r /x perform on a corrupted external drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, chkdsk

I have a couple of HDD that are damaged or with bad sectors. One of my HDD was BitLocker protected and I couldn't open it no more. I removed BitLocker hoping that I can probably access the HDD. Since I remove BitLocker I was able to used diskpart to removed write protected files with success so I decide to perform chkdsk /f /r /x to see if I can fix the device and extract all the file that I can. My question is: Is it safe to use my computer while chkdsk is working? I'm asking this question because I understand that /f /r switches are more complex tasks for the computer.

Comment: I would be inclined to let CHKDSK run by itself until done. The risk of otherwise using your computer is probably not large but not worth it.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right and this is why I'm asking it's just that it's a long process but I'm going to have to respect that thank you

Comment: If the disk in question is not the system disk, then you using your machine, should have no effect on the success or failure of the scan.  I hope you know chkdsk won't fix corrupt sectors, if anything, as a result of those scans those files on those sectors will simply be lost.

Answer (score 0):

`chkdsk`, and much more so `chkdsk /f`, needs complete and exclusive
access to the disk.
Without it, the result is the error message
"Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another process".

This is why it cannot fix the Windows system disk in the normal
system mode, simply because Windows is using it, and it will then
set a dirty bit to the disk volume and reboot the computer.

[image]

This doesn't prevent one from running `chkdsk` on a non-system disk,
because then `chkdsk` will be able to gain a complete lock of the disk.
It's only the system disk that needs to be processed in
offline mode.